# Why is Visual Studio 2012 generating a *.vshost.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, vshost.exe

"Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" is not ticked:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozrsg.png

Am I missing something?

Forgive the simplicity of my question.  My Google-fu is not strong enough to wade through all the "what does vshost do?"